# Ruby gems on OSx

Tags: rubygems

I have installed a gem using gem install command on Mac OSX. It got installed under ./library/ruby/gems/1.8/gems//lib/

Now I would like to use the functionality from this Gem. However when using it in the code, it could not access the objects from the same. Please help in resolving this.

Thanks!

Comment: Its giving error: `require': no such file to load -- <object> (LoadError)
 from driver.rb:2

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
require 'rubygems'
```

before your require